# How to horizontally align multiple select lists when populated with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap css and AngularJS and have a problem horizontally aligning a label with 2 select lists:

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/664q5/

The first line has a select box that is populated using AngularJS:

```
            <div style="background-color: lightcoral"  class="form-group">
                <label for="expirymonth" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Expiry Date</label>
                <select  ng-model="expirymonth" ng-change="setcardmonth(expirymonth)" ng-options="e.month for e in cardmonth" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"/>/
                <select ng-model="expiryyear" id="expyear" ng-change="setcardyear(expiryyear)" ng-options="y.year for y in cardyear" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" />
            </div>
```

Only the first select list is displayed on the form

The second list is using regular select with options.

```
            <div style="background-color: lightcoral"  class="form-group">
                <label for="expirymonth" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Expiry Date</label>
                 <select><option>12</option></select>
                  <select><option>2014</option></select>
            </div>
```

Here you can see that the Expiry date label is aligned with the select options perfectly fine.

Can someone please explain to me why only one select list is displayed when populated with AngularJS?

Answer (score 3):

Your select tags should not be self closing.  The [correct syntax](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) is:
`<select`
`ng-model=""`
`[name=""]`
`[required=""]`
`[ng-required=""]`
`[ng-options=""]>`
`...`
`</select>`

Additionally, jsfiddle doesn't like the way you were including angular.  See this fork of your example: [jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/A2MGY/](http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/A2MGY/)